# Laravel "Can't write image data to path ({$path})"

Tags: laravel, file-permissions, laravel-6, directory-permissions

I create Laravel project on ubuntu 18.4.

I upload my project in `/var/www/html/` and i upload images in `home/sun/download/`

after run this code:

```
$imageName = "thumb_{$size}.{$extension}";
$routePath = $url . '/products/' . $product->id . '/';

Image::make($file->path())->resize($size, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($routePath, $imageName);
```

Show this error:

```
"Can't write image data to path (/home/sun/download/products/2/)"
```

How to issue this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Permission issue, Have you tried using the Storage facade?

```php
$Image->save(Storage::disk('your_disk')->path($routePath), $quality);
```

---

That's how i stored images in my situation

```php
Image = Image::make($source);
$Image->getCore()->stripImage();

# Resize the image and save
$Image->fit($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
     $constraint->upsize();
});

return $Image->save(Storage::disk('public')->path($destination), $quality);
```

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: you are writing the image outside your project, you need to check if the user running laravel has the permissions to write to that directory (os issue not laravel itself), using the Storage facade provided by Laravel will act as a quick workaround, but it will store your data in your laravel application in `/var/www/html/storage/...` where it can write files, because that storage folder has the 755/644 permission, so what you need to look at if you want to store files outside your Laravel folder is linux folders permissions

Comment: I need upload in `home/sun/download/`

Comment: I suggested new tags that will help